# Improve scraper speed

Tags: c#, web-scraping, proxy

I am creating a small program to scrape proxies, it works correctly, the only drawback is that it takes too long, I have tried to use parallel to shorten the time but it is still very slow, is there any way to speed up the process?

```
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            string proxy = "";
            int x = 0;
            Console.Title = "Scraped proxies: 0";
            string apisUnParsed =
                "http://proxydb.net/\nhttp://www.cybersyndrome.net/pla.html\nhttp://www.proxz.com/proxy_list_ca_0.html\nhttp://www.proxz.com/proxy_list_high_anonymous_0.html\nhttp://proxy.ipcn.org/proxylist2.html\nhttp://torvpn.com/proxylist.html\nhttp://www.proxz.com/proxy_list_anonymous_us_0.html\nhttp://www.proxz.com/proxy_list_cn_ssl_0.html\nhttp://www.proxz.com/proxy_list_jp_0.html\nhttp://www.proxz.com/proxy_list_uk_0.html\nhttp://dogdev.net/Proxy/US?port=80\nhttp://www.atomintersoft.com/products/alive-proxy/proxy-list/\nhttp://www.atomintersoft.com/anonymous_proxy_list\nhttp://www.proxz.com/proxy_list_fr_0.html\nhttp://www.atomintersoft.com/high_anonymity_elite_proxy_list\nhttp://dogdev.net/Proxy/all\nhttp://www.proxylists.net/\nhttp://www.httptunnel.ge/ProxyListForFree.aspx\nhttp://www.proxylists.net/proxylist.shtml?HTTP\nhttp://anon-proxy.ru/|html|0\nhttp://proxies.my-proxy.com/proxy-list-1.html\nhttp://globalproxies.blogspot.com/\nhttp://proxies.my-proxy.com/proxy-list-2.html\nhttp://anon-proxy.ru/\nhttp://www.socks24.org/feeds/posts/default\nhttp://www.proxylists.net/http.txt\nhttp://aa8.narod.ru/index/0-9\nhttp://www.proxylists.net/http_highanon.txt\nhttp://proxylists.net/http.txt\nhttp://free-proxy-list.net/anonymous-proxy.html\nhttp://proxylists.net/http_highanon.txt\nhttp://ab57.ru/downloads/proxylist.txt\nhttp://www.us-proxy.org/\nhttps://raw.githubusercontent.com/clarketm/proxy-list/master/proxy-list.txt\nhttp://free-socks24.blogspot.in//\nhttp://globalproxies.blogspot.com/search/label/US%20Proxies\nhttp://freepremiumproxy.blogspot.com\nhttp://aa8.narod.ru/index/0-10\nhttp://proxysearcher.sourceforge.net/Proxy%20List.php%3Ftype%3Dhttp\nhttp://rootjazz.com/proxies/proxies.txt\nhttps://chinaproxylist.wordpress.com/feed/\nhttp://sslproxies24.blogspot.nl/feeds/posts/default\nhttp://www.sslproxies24.top/feeds/posts/default\nhttp://proxy-heaven.blogspot.com/\nhttp://sslproxies24.blogspot.ca/feeds/posts/default\nhttp://aa8.narod.ru/index/0-8\nhttps://free-socks24.blogspot.in/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss\nhttp://free-socks24.blogspot.in/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss\nhttp://alexa.lr2b.com/proxylist.txt\nhttp://absentius.narod.ru/\nhttps://autoproxyblog.wordpress.com/feed/\nhttp://www.changeips.com/\nhttp://mmm-downloads.at.ua/blog\nhttp://feeds.feedburner.com/AnonymousDailyProxyList\nhttp://freeproxylistsdaily.blogspot.in/feeds/posts/default\nhttp://proxyserverlist-24.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default\nhttp://proxy-hunter.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default\nhttps://proxy50-50.blogspot.com/\nhttp://free-fresh-proxy-daily.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default\nhttp://rootjazz.com/proxies/proxies.txt\nhttp://www.live-socks.net/feeds/posts/default\nhttp://www.socks24.org/feeds/posts/default\nhttp://www.proxyserverlist24.top/feeds/posts/default\nhttp://proxysearcher.sourceforge.net/Proxy%20List.php?type=http\nhttps://free-proxy-list.net/\nhttps://proxy-spider.com/api/proxies.example.txt\nhttp://proxysearcher.sourceforge.net/Proxy%20List.php?type=socks\"\nhttp://proxysearcher.sourceforge.net/Proxy%20List.php\nhttps://raw.githubusercontent.com/TheSpeedX/SOCKS-List/master/socks4.txt\nhttps://raw.githubusercontent.com/ShiftyTR/Proxy-List/master/socks4.txt\nhttps://raw.githubusercontent.com/TheSpeedX/SOCKS-List/master/socks5.txt\nhttps://raw.githubusercontent.com/ShiftyTR/Proxy-List/master/http.txt\nhttps://raw.githubusercontent.com/ShiftyTR/Proxy-List/master/socks5.txt\nhttps://raw.githubusercontent.com/hookzof/socks5_list/master/proxy.txt\nhttps://raw.githubusercontent.com/TheSpeedX/SOCKS-List/master/http.txt\nhttps://proxysource.org/api/proxies/getWorkingProxies?apiToken=17580e4438910c287cef15dca10b7912a26&latencyMax=10000&latencyMin=0&outputMode=plaintext\nhttp://spys.me/proxy.txt\nhttps://api.proxyscrape.com/?request=getproxies&proxytype=all&country=all&ssl=all&anonymity=all\nhttps://raw.githubusercontent.com/clarketm/proxy-list/master/proxy-list-raw.txt\nhttps://raw.githubusercontent.com/TheSpeedX/PROXY-List/master/http.txt\nhttp://pubproxy.com/api/proxy?type=http&format=txt&limit=5\nhttp://pubproxy.com/api/proxy?type=http&format=txt&limit=5&https=true\nhttps://www.proxy-list.download/api/v1/get?type=http\nhttps://www.proxy-list.download/api/v1/get?type=https\nhttps://api.proxyscrape.com/v2/?request=displayproxies&protocol=http&timeout=10000&country=all&ssl=all&anonymity=all\nhttps://raw.githubusercontent.com/TheSpeedX/PROXY-List/master/socks4.txt\nhttp://pubproxy.com/api/proxy?type=socks4&format=txt&limit=5\nhttps://www.proxy-list.download/api/v1/get?type=socks4\nhttps://api.proxyscrape.com/v2/?request=displayproxies&protocol=socks4&timeout=10000&country=all&anonymity=all\nhttps://raw.githubusercontent.com/TheSpeedX/PROXY-List/master/socks5.txt\nhttp://pubproxy.com/api/proxy?type=socks5&format=txt&limit=5\nhttps://www.proxy-list.download/api/v1/get?type=socks5\nhttps://api.proxyscrape.com/v2/?request=displayproxies&protocol=socks5&timeout=10000&country=all&anonymity=all";
            string[] APIS = apisUnParsed.Split('\n');
            List<string> proxiesScraped = new List<string>();
            WebClient connect = new WebClient();
            connect.Headers["User-Agent"] =
                "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)";
            stopwatch.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < APIS.Length; i++)
            {
                
                Console.WriteLine($"\r\nTHIS API IS: {APIS[i]}");
                try
                {
                    proxy += connect.DownloadString(APIS[i]);
                    Parallel.For(0, Regex.Matches(proxy, @"\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+:\d+").Count, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((Environment.ProcessorCount * 0.75) * 3.0)) }, j =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(Regex.Matches(proxy, @"\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+:\d+")[j]);
                        proxiesScraped.Add(Regex.Matches(proxy, @"\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+:\d+")[j].ToString());
                        x++;
                        Console.Title = $"Scraped proxies: {x.ToString()}";
                    });
                    proxy = "";
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                }
            }
            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);

            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Check memory usage using Task Manager to see if slow time is due to memory.  Also check Task Manager Performance to see if Internet speed is the issue.

Comment: One optimisation that I can see is to [cache your regex and set to compiled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/compilation-and-reuse-in-regular-expressions).

Comment: @Hayden Thanks, it works, the speed increased in a 30% approximate, but i need some more of speed but your answer has helped me

Comment: There is a minor mistake(s) with the Code formatting in your Question, the first line is not getting displayed because the leading triple-backticks "```" need to be in a separate first line, as well as the trailing ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This takes around 2500ms to execute on my machine.

```cs
private static async Task Main()
{
    var proxyUrlToParse =
        "http://proxydb.net/\nhttp://www.cybersyndrome.net/pla.html\nhttp://www.proxz.com/proxy_list_ca_0.html\nhttp://www.proxz.com/proxy_list_high_anonymous_0.html\nhttp://proxy.ipcn.org/proxylist2.html\nhttp://torvpn.com/proxylist.html\nhttp://www.proxz.com/proxy_list_anonymous_us_0.html\nhttp://www.proxz.com/proxy_list_cn_ssl_0.html\nhttp://www.proxz.com/proxy_list_jp_0.html\nhttp://www.proxz.com/proxy_list_uk_0.html\nhttp://dogdev.net/Proxy/US?port=80\nhttp://www.atomintersoft.com/products/alive-proxy/proxy-list/\nhttp://www.atomintersoft.com/anonymous_proxy_list\nhttp://www.proxz.com/proxy_list_fr_0.html\nhttp://www.atomintersoft.com/high_anonymity_elite_proxy_list\nhttp://dogdev.net/Proxy/all\nhttp://www.proxylists.net/\nhttp://www.httptunnel.ge/ProxyListForFree.aspx\nhttp://www.proxylists.net/proxylist.shtml?HTTP\nhttp://anon-proxy.ru/|html|0\nhttp://proxies.my-proxy.com/proxy-list-1.html\nhttp://globalproxies.blogspot.com/\nhttp://proxies.my-proxy.com/proxy-list-2.html\nhttp://anon-proxy.ru/\nhttp://www.socks24.org/feeds/posts/default\nhttp://www.proxylists.net/http.txt\nhttp://aa8.narod.ru/index/0-9\nhttp://www.proxylists.net/http_highanon.txt\nhttp://proxylists.net/http.txt\nhttp://free-proxy-list.net/anonymous-proxy.html\nhttp://proxylists.net/http_highanon.txt\nhttp://ab57.ru/downloads/proxylist.txt\nhttp://www.us-proxy.org/\nhttps://raw.githubusercontent.com/clarketm/proxy-list/master/proxy-list.txt\nhttp://free-socks24.blogspot.in//\nhttp://globalproxies.blogspot.com/search/label/US%20Proxies\nhttp://freepremiumproxy.blogspot.com\nhttp://aa8.narod.ru/index/0-10\nhttp://proxysearcher.sourceforge.net/Proxy%20List.php%3Ftype%3Dhttp\nhttp://rootjazz.com/proxies/proxies.txt\nhttps://chinaproxylist.wordpress.com/feed/\nhttp://sslproxies24.blogspot.nl/feeds/posts/default\nhttp://www.sslproxies24.top/feeds/posts/default\nhttp://proxy-heaven.blogspot.com/\nhttp://sslproxies24.blogspot.ca/feeds/posts/default\nhttp://aa8.narod.ru/index/0-8\nhttps://free-socks24.blogspot.in/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss\nhttp://free-socks24.blogspot.in/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss\nhttp://alexa.lr2b.com/proxylist.txt\nhttp://absentius.narod.ru/\nhttps://autoproxyblog.wordpress.com/feed/\nhttp://www.changeips.com/\nhttp://mmm-downloads.at.ua/blog\nhttp://feeds.feedburner.com/AnonymousDailyProxyList\nhttp://freeproxylistsdaily.blogspot.in/feeds/posts/default\nhttp://proxyserverlist-24.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default\nhttp://proxy-hunter.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default\nhttps://proxy50-50.blogspot.com/\nhttp://free-fresh-proxy-daily.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default\nhttp://rootjazz.com/proxies/proxies.txt\nhttp://www.live-socks.net/feeds/posts/default\nhttp://www.socks24.org/feeds/posts/default\nhttp://www.proxyserverlist24.top/feeds/posts/default\nhttp://proxysearcher.sourceforge.net/Proxy%20List.php?type=http\nhttps://free-proxy-list.net/\nhttps://proxy-spider.com/api/proxies.example.txt\nhttp://proxysearcher.sourceforge.net/Proxy%20List.php?type=socks\"\nhttp://proxysearcher.sourceforge.net/Proxy%20List.php\nhttps://raw.githubusercontent.com/TheSpeedX/SOCKS-List/master/socks4.txt\nhttps://raw.githubusercontent.com/ShiftyTR/Proxy-List/master/socks4.txt\nhttps://raw.githubusercontent.com/TheSpeedX/SOCKS-List/master/socks5.txt\nhttps://raw.githubusercontent.com/ShiftyTR/Proxy-List/master/http.txt\nhttps://raw.githubusercontent.com/ShiftyTR/Proxy-List/master/socks5.txt\nhttps://raw.githubusercontent.com/hookzof/socks5_list/master/proxy.txt\nhttps://raw.githubusercontent.com/TheSpeedX/SOCKS-List/master/http.txt\nhttps://proxysource.org/api/proxies/getWorkingProxies?apiToken=17580e4438910c287cef15dca10b7912a26&latencyMax=10000&latencyMin=0&outputMode=plaintext\nhttp://spys.me/proxy.txt\nhttps://api.proxyscrape.com/?request=getproxies&proxytype=all&country=all&ssl=all&anonymity=all\nhttps://raw.githubusercontent.com/clarketm/proxy-list/master/proxy-list-raw.txt\nhttps://raw.githubusercontent.com/TheSpeedX/PROXY-List/master/http.txt\nhttp://pubproxy.com/api/proxy?type=http&format=txt&limit=5\nhttp://pubproxy.com/api/proxy?type=http&format=txt&limit=5&https=true\nhttps://www.proxy-list.download/api/v1/get?type=http\nhttps://www.proxy-list.download/api/v1/get?type=https\nhttps://api.proxyscrape.com/v2/?request=displayproxies&protocol=http&timeout=10000&country=all&ssl=all&anonymity=all\nhttps://raw.githubusercontent.com/TheSpeedX/PROXY-List/master/socks4.txt\nhttp://pubproxy.com/api/proxy?type=socks4&format=txt&limit=5\nhttps://www.proxy-list.download/api/v1/get?type=socks4\nhttps://api.proxyscrape.com/v2/?request=displayproxies&protocol=socks4&timeout=10000&country=all&anonymity=all\nhttps://raw.githubusercontent.com/TheSpeedX/PROXY-List/master/socks5.txt\nhttp://pubproxy.com/api/proxy?type=socks5&format=txt&limit=5\nhttps://www.proxy-list.download/api/v1/get?type=socks5\nhttps://api.proxyscrape.com/v2/?request=displayproxies&protocol=socks5&timeout=10000&country=all&anonymity=all";
    string[] urls = proxyUrlToParse.Split('\n');
    var blockingCollection = new BlockingCollection<string>();
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    
    IEnumerable<Task> producerTasks = urls.Select(url => Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            blockingCollection.Add(await client.GetStringAsync(url));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    })).ToArray();

    Task<List<string>> consumerTask = Task.Run(() => blockingCollection
        .GetConsumingEnumerable()
        .AsParallel()
        .WithMergeOptions(ParallelMergeOptions.NotBuffered)
        .WithDegreeOfParallelism(3)
        .SelectMany(c =>
        {
            return Regex.Matches(c, @"\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+:\d+").Select(m => m.Value);
        }).ToList());

    await Task.WhenAll(producerTasks);

    blockingCollection.CompleteAdding();

    List<string> proxies = await consumerTask;

    Console.WriteLine($"Completed fetching {proxies.Count} proxies in {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
}
```